# Is it possible to accept an answer as someone other than the OP?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

**On Stack Overflow, is there a way for the community to accept an answer to a question, if the OP has been inactive for a long period of time and the answer clearly should be accepted?**

Example:
*[What are the allowed character in snapchat username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819830/what-are-the-allowed-character-in-snapchat-username)*

The answer is taken from Snapchat's own guide and clearly answers the question beyond doubt. I have read it and can confirm that this should be the accepted answer. The OP was last seen in April 2017 according to their user profile.

**Is there a way for the community to accept the given answer?**

- Can someone with more reputation than myself do this already?
- Or is this a feature that could potentially be added to Stack Overflow? For example, this could work similar to the "close" feature, where at least x people have to vote for an answer to be accepted.

Comment: No, there is not.  The OP is signaling that s/he did not found any of the answers useful, (or has copy/pasted out their homework answer and just disappeared).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that! What is the process for requesting for this functionality to be added as a new feature?

Comment: Can you explain why is it useful? Why is upvoting it to the top not enough (quality control is the reason why upvote is created in the first place)?

Comment: The closure of the question having an accepted answer and seeing the green tick. If upvoting an answer to the top is enough, why is there a green tick feature?

Comment: The question is considered "answered" if it has an accepted answer or at least 1 upvoted answers. The green tick (acceptance) is only to show that it's (supposedly) the best answer *for OP* (not necessarily for everyone).

Comment: @Ben *"why is there a green tick feature?"* why indeed. Good question. Because it seemed a good reason at the time, most likely. I wonder more why it is still there. The usual argument is that it is valuable to know what worked for the person who asked the question. Well, agree to disagree :) Votes are enough.